# Convert object column to array type - pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Im reading a SQL query with pd.read_sql().

One of the columns of the query has array type, but Pandas doesn't recognize this as an array, but as a string.

How do I change de type of the column to be able to iterate over its values?

This is the df head:

```
        main_ID                      related_ids
1      00088381096959               [PRDKQUOV2JAR17RD, PRDKPYH11Z4GFZOV]
2       0011509002051               [PRCOFOK9MJ2CTABE, PRSESJD2K7PFYVUM]
3       0011509002051               [OSPAA89FNMJH9UWK, OSPW2JJQ949ZHNS3]
4       0019954960568               [PRDORZT50BDS1Z6H, PRDHG07MVG1YCX2N]
```

Then I will need to do something like this:

```
for item,row in df.iterrows():
    for id in row['related_ids']:
         code...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

via `strip()` and `split()`:

```
df['related_ids']=df['related_ids'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')
```

**OR**

If you need `np.array()` then use:

```
df['related_ids']=df['related_ids'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',').map(np.array)
```

Comment: with `pd.eval()` show this error 
`pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'OSPRSPQK33EAY22L' is not defined`.

With `strip()` and `split()` it works well, I'll only need to remove the `" ' "`, but is ok. Thank you to much